# Call audio quality measurement with Non-Reference files

Tags: c++, c, audio, call, telephony

How can i measure call audio quality for distinguishing local call and international call (which through many codecs). All i have is just a degraded output files (No-References) ?

Comment: I'd be surprised if international calls go through many codecs, in this day and age. The backbone is pretty much all-IP these days. No real need for compression

Comment: More importantly, I have no idea what's being asked here. "No-reference files", what does that even mean?